# Using curl to download an image from an url that has no file extension

Tags: curl

I want to download the image on

```
https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1/
```

with `curl`.

`curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png > image.png` **works** **fine**!
(from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330737/ubuntu-using-curl-to-download-an-image)

The problem with `https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1/` is that it has no file extension, like `.jpg` or `.png`.

**Attempts**:

1. `curl https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1 > test.jpg`

   [image: test.jpg]
2. `curl -O https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1/`

   > ... Remote file name has no length! ...
3. `curl -O https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1/ > test.jpg`

   > ... Remote file name has no length! ...

and attempts with `curl -Ov` (verbose) and other attempts with no success.

Is it possible with `curl`?

Comment: Don't forget the last  `/` also curl have a convinient option wich is -o to precise the output file. Anyway both works on my computer. `curl https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1/ -o test.jpg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ curl -o x.jpg  https://lorempixel.com/1280/320/nature/1/ 
$ file x.jpg
x.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 70", baseline, precision 8, 1280x320, frames 3
```